# How can we be sure of the authenticity of the bible

Tags: bible

How can we be sure the bible we are reading today is what the authors wrote down and its not corrupted? And with the different bibles etc niv, catholic bible, king james bible how do i know which one is the most authentic?

Comment: Thomas, you're asking two different and very broad questions here – who put the Bible together, and how we can be sure of its reliability.  Which do you want to ask?

Comment: Sorry i got two questions who put it all together and how can we sure of the authenticity

Comment: Then I'd strongly recommend asking the two questions separately, considering how broad they each are.  It would also be helpful if you more clearly specified what exactly you are looking for.  For example, in the first question, are you asking about the Catholic Bible or the Protestant Bible or the Greek Orthodox Bible?  By "put together," do you mean when it was first established as a canon?

Comment: Here's a related question: [How can we be so sure about the authenticity and genuineness of all the new “versions” and translations of the Canonical Bible?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/35569/21576)